# Redis not blocking when running slow commands

Tags: redis

We're having a severe config/product bug on our installation. We've been experiencing concurrency related errors that we've been blaming to Jedis usage, but it seems that it might be a product / config issue.

This is a single redis installation with over 4M keys. Whenever we run a long running command from redis-cli, like a keys *, our client code (Jedis based) starts to throw errors, like trying to cast a string into a binary (typical concurrency errors in Jedis conf). The worst scenario is that sometimes it seems that it returns wrong keys. We were using a Jedis instance in each actor instance, so it shouldn't be an issue but we changed to JedisPool nevertheless. But the problem remained (we are using Jedis 2.6.2).

But the main thing was when trying from different redis-cli. We run KEYS * that stays a long time running and then a GET command which returned. It was our understanding that the KEYS * should block everyone, but the GET command keeps working. This also happens with a SLEEP command.

Is this related to a config setting or this is something that shouldn't happen, or the KEYS command isn't blocking and my problem lies elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

[Redis.io documentation for `KEYS`](http://redis.io/commands/keys) clearly states that `KEYS` is a debug command and should not be used in production:

> **Warning**: consider [KEYS](http://redis.io/commands/keys) as a command that should only be used in
>   production environments with extreme care. It may ruin performance
>   when it is executed against large databases. This command is intended
>   for debugging and special operations, such as changing your keyspace
>   layout. Don't use [KEYS](http://redis.io/commands/keys) in your regular application code. If you're
>   looking for a way to find keys in a subset of your keyspace, consider
>   using [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) or [sets](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#sets).